# How do I calculate the running total SQL statement when selecting only a portion of the data?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

How do I select ID 6-9 and calculate the running total in a SQL statement?

This would display the same running total in the picture and would not start from ID 6:

[image]

Comment: Start here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ And please only tag relevant DBMS as the answers are not the same for mysql and sql-server.

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include the code you have already tried, and an explanation of how it is not working.  Also, you may find this helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MJH Please see my comment below that includes the query and results

Comment: @MJH *Plese see my answer i posted below*

Comment: @JRosa, your answer is in danger of being deleted, because is is not an actual answer to the question. Please edit your original question so as to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

If SQL Server 2012+ you can use the window functions

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Amount int)
Insert Into @YourTable values (1,80),(2,11),(3,123),(4,47),(5,8),(6,500),(7,49),(8,27),(9,34),(10,56),(11,82),(12,17)

-- If 2012+  
Select *
      ,RunningTotal = sum(Amount) over (Order By ID)
 From @YourTable
 Where ID between 6 and 9
```

Returns

```
ID  Amount  RunningTotal
6   500     500
7   49      549
8   27      576
9   34      610
```

If below 2012

```
Select A.ID
      ,A.Amount
      ,RunningTotal = sum(B.Amount)
 From @YourTable A
 Join @YourTable B on (B.ID <=A.ID and B.ID between 6 and 9)
 Where A.ID between 6 and 9
 Group By A.ID,A.Amount
 Order By A.ID
```

Comment: Hey John, the database is over millions of rows long. How would something be written differently, to prevent inserting each individual row into "@YourTable"?

Comment: @JRosa  That is just a table variable for demonstrative purposes.  Remove the first two lines in my answer and change  (at)YourTable to your actual table name

Comment: Please see my comment below

Comment: @JRosa I see no comment

Comment: it's the answer i posted below your answer. It includes my query and the results to give a sense of what i need the running total for

Answer (score 0):

you can use ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING - window function to calculate running total

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Amount int)
Insert Into @YourTable values (1,80),(2,11),(3,123),(4,47),(5,8),(6,500),(7,49),(8,27),(9,34),(10,56),(11,82),(12,17)

select *, sum(amount) over (order by id rows unbounded preceding) as RunningTotal from @yourTable
```

You can apply condition accordingly